# Dynamically Adding Columns to WordPress Custom Database Table for Each Post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Basically I've built a form which allows users to enter what day/time they watched one of our videos each week. I've got the videos set up as a custom post type called 'Themes', and there is a row in the form for each theme, with columns for each day of the week and a selector for the time on each day. I've already got the rows in the form feeding dynamically from custom post types so that there is a row for each theme that exists, and one will be added each time a theme is added... This is where the problem comes in because I need to find a way to dynamicize the mysql table in the same way, where I'll need to create a new set of columns for each new theme dynamically.

So given that information, I've followed [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-database-tables-creating-the-table--wp-28124) in order to create my table dynamically via the WordPress API through a plugin. What I'm unclear on is how I can manipulate the portion of the statement below to have it create a new column for each post in my custom post type of 'Themes'. I think if I'm able to figure that bit out I'll be able to sort out the rest as well.

```
  $sql_create_table = "CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->tracker_entry_submission} (
      theme_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
 ) $charset_collate; ";
```

Comment: So you want different columns for different rows in the same table?

Comment: Though that's the way the form is laid out on the front end, and it is the ideal way to view this information, I was sort of working under the assumption that in the db this data would have to be laid out flat in a single row. This would mean each new theme would add 6 columns; one for the theme id and then 1 for each day of the week where the time would be entered.

Comment: definately not what you would want to do.  I'll put in an answer

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft term for what you are attempting to do is sparesely populated fields.  In MySQL terms...the model you will want to look up is Entity Attributt Value or EAV.  EAV is a table that holds key, column name, column value...this allows for rows to have different column names.  Do some research on the EAV term (google!) and see if it meets what you need here.

*** disclaimer - EAV is not the most scalable and hits issues when you attempt to index and the sort.  It's ultimately an anti-pattern, but it works for smaller sparsely populated data sets.  Plan on having over a million rows setup like this?

Once you have the data laid out like that, you will want to 'pivot' the data out of the table.  Tons of pivot examples on Stack Overflow...potentially the most frequent asked question with the sql tag on it.